# How can I get the following value of the property in a TextBlock which has its source as Data Binding in a Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, list, xaml, binding, nested

Please have a look at this image to understand my scenario

[image: scenario]

So I have the above scenario in my Windows Phone application where I have a ListBox with the below layout.

My XAML for the ListBox

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="llsIceCreamBrands" Margin="0,54,0,0" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,40">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="3">
                                        <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding IceCreamBrandImage }" Margin="3,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Grid Margin="20,-5,0,0" Height="250" >
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IceCreamBrandName }" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="34" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="184" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="1" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="35" Height="Auto" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IceCreamBrandFlavour }" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe WP" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Opacity="0.7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="140"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

In C# Code:

```
void GetIceCreamBrands()
    {
        string mystring = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands.Count; i++)
        {
            var bmp = new BitmapImage();

            if (dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[i].HasArt)
            {
                bmp.SetSource(dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[i].GetImage());
            }
            else
            {
                bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                bmp.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/Images/IceCreams/Placeholder.png", UriKind.Relative);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands.Count; j++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[j].Flavour.Count; k++)
                {
                    sourceFlavourList.Add(new Flavour
                    {
                        FlavourBrand = dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[j].Name,
                        BrandFlavourName = dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[j].Flavour[k].Name
                    });

                }

            }

            sourceIceCreamBrands.Add(new IceCreamBrands
            {
                IceCreamBrandName = dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[i].Name,
                IceCreamBrandImage = bmp,
                IceCreamBrandFlavour = "Get Flavours here for the particular brand somehow?"
            });

        }

        llsIceCreamBrands.ItemsSource = sourceIceCreamBrands.ToList();
    }
```

I have the above method in my code which successfully gets the brands and their images, but the flavours are also a `Collection` which I tried to get in a single string by using

```
string mystring = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sourceFlavourList.Select(x => x.IceCreamBrandFlavourName));
```

**But this returns the same values for both Ben&Jerrys and Haagen-Dazs - which is an amalgamation of both brands' flavours.**

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you define the variable 'sourceFlavourList' within GetIceCreamBrands(), so I assume you have this defined elsewhere in your code. This would explain why you see the full list of flavours (from both brands) as you keep adding all flavours to this one variable.

So instead of using this full list variable, you would need to bind to a per brand list (which you DO have in your result)., so you can use the same linq you have, but with a different source variable).

Try something like this:

```
var flavours = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[j].Flavour.Select(x => x.Name));
    sourceIceCreamBrands.Add(new IceCreamBrands
    {
         IceCreamBrandName = dc.IceCreams[cID].Brands[i].Name,
         IceCreamBrandImage = bmp,
         IceCreamBrandFlavour = flavours
    });
```

Comment: Hello there, Thanks for replying but this time it returns flavours from the last brand into all brands :(

Comment: Can you check the result of sourceIceCreamBrands at the end of GetIceCreamBrands()? Is it what you expect (two items, each with the correct image and list of flavours)? If so, do you bind to this variable (sourceIceCreamBrands) correctly?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct image and the correct brand name but I think I have just been able to figure it out...

Comment: I have just figured it out! I created a new `List <string>()` and added the `var flavours` to the list everytime `j++` occured and when the `i++` occured - I got the flavours by specifying `[i]` as the index for the `List <string>` :)

Comment: That's why I prefer to use Linq instead of indexes, especially multi-dimensional ones, like this. I'm glad you figured it out.